# Tomcat server - send warning emails on crash

Tags: tomcat

Is there some way to set the tomcat server to send warning messages on crash (ie. tomcat is stopped an I'll receive the email)?

Comment: To keep Tomcat running you can use a supervisor like [`runit`](http://smarden.org/runit/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, have a separate program (on a separate machine) running which is pinging the server (requesting a webpage every 10 seconds, etc). If that program fails to send a response, have it email you.